# botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed on aws3 endpoint

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

i'm trying to download from s3 public bucket and got ssl error, while 2 weeks ago everything works and i didnt change anything on my workspace.
i'm not sure why?

**Meta**

```
python: Python 3.6.9 
pip Version: 21.3.1
requierments:
boto3==1.21.13
botocore==1.24.13
importlib-resources==5.4.0
jmespath==0.10.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
s3transfer==0.5.2
six==1.16.0
tabulate==0.8.9
tqdm==4.63.0
urllib3==1.26.8
zipp==3.6.0
```

i'm trying to download from s3 amazon public bucket.

```
    import boto3
    import botocore
    import urllib3

    from botocore.handlers import disable_signing

    s3_resource = boto3.resource(
                "s3",
                endpoint_url="https://s3.amazonaws.com",
                verify=False,
                region_name=None,
                aws_access_key_id=None,
                aws_secret_access_key=None,
            )
    s3_resource.meta.client.meta.events.register('choose-signer.s3.*', disable_signing)
    
    s3_resource.Bucket("mybucket").download_file(
                    "logo_detection_data/images/1.jpg", "/logo_detection_data/images/1.jpg", ExtraArgs=None)
```

Error:

```
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/logo_detection_data/images/1.jpg [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```